# Cannot access CSS file from HTML text

Tags: css, html

Here is a sample of my code:

```
<!doctype HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Homepage</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="C:/Users/OneDrive/Programming/HTML/css/test.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>This is a heading.</h1>
        <p1>This is a paragraph.</p1>

        <ul>
            <li>This is the first element of a list</li>
            <li>This is the second one.</li>
        </ul>

    <button type="button" onclick="alert('That tickles...')">Press me!</button><br>
    <button type="button" onclick="">I do nothing. :-(</button>

    </body>
</html>
```

What the situation is my CSS file...

```
p {
    font-family: Courier New;
    color: white;
    background-color: lightblue;
}
```

... is located in the following way:

```
HTML/
..../home.html
..../css/
......../test.css
```

I've tried to access the css via `href="css/test.css"` but to no avail. What am I doing wrong?

P.S. Any optimisations to my code?

Comment: Use the [browser console (dev tools)](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`). The dev tools provide a **Network** tab. Please confirm: Is the resource _found_ (e.g. HTTP 200 response)? If not, which _actual URL_ is requested?

Comment: As of HTML5 type="text/css" is not required anymore.

Comment: @Xufox I get `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`

Comment: @BUZZYSIN it is in appropriate to post solutions within questions or `[solved]` in the title of a question. If you need to indicate a solution, please use the green check mark. If you need to answer your own question, please post an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is correct:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/test.css">
```

But in your code isn't any **p** tag only **p1**. So replace this:

```
p {
    font-family: Courier New;
    color: white;
    background-color: lightblue;
}
```

With this:

```
p1 {
    font-family: Courier New;
    color: white;
    background-color: lightblue;
}
```

(Sorry for my english. I'm from czech republic)

Comment: ...or even better, change `<p1>` to `<p>`? :o)

Comment: @agrm Yes, it is better, but if you set **background-color** the result is different in both tags. (Ex. https://jsfiddle.net/mozkomor05/3fuxqrog/)

Comment: @DavidMoškoř My point is that `<p>` is a valid HTML element. `<p1>` is not. The visual difference in your example is simply because `<p>` is recognized by browsers as a block level element by default, whereas `<p1>`, unknown to the browser, is rendered as an inline element. Add `p1{display:block}` and they will both appear as blocks. Or `p{display:inline}` and they will both be inline...

Comment: Thanks for explain. I always thought that `<p1>` is a valid html tag in older HTML versions.

Answer (score 1):

When you are accessing local files, you have to specify the file URI scheme (`file:///`):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="file:///C:/Users/OneDrive/Programming/HTML/css/test.css">
```

or use a relative path:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/test.css">
```

Comment: I tried the second option as stated in my question to no avail. It _should_ work, but it doesn't and I'm not sure why.

Edit: I didn't try the suggestion, I'll see if it works.

Comment: Did you try preceding your file path with the file URI scheme (`file:///`) as I suggested?

Comment: The second way works if your html is in `html` folder.

Comment: @FarzinKanzi that is correct, it is in the `HTML` folder.

Comment: Your suggestion worked in getting rid of `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`, @agrm, but I don't see any changes in my webpage. Is my code wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/test.css">
```

Comment: It's his source, I'm just answering about his problem with the css file  location, if you want to get in other details not related to his problem, you can open another topic. Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

I would say check the spelling of the filename of your actual css file.  Make sure it actually is `test.css` and not `tst.css` or `tesy.css` or some other typo.  Check the folder name for typos too.

If your `css` file is somewhere inside your project folder just like your `HMTL` file I'm guessing a typo has to be the issue. For example, if your project structure looks like this

```
yourProjectFolder
||
||_ index.html
|
|__ stylesFolder
      |
      |_ test.css
```

Your script would have to look like this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesFolder/test.css">
```

If this is indeed the way you're targeting your file and you're getting errors you have to be spelling something wrong somewhere along the way.